# google autocomplete not returning lat long

Tags: google-maps

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&libraries=places" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
function initialize() {

    var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function(){
        console.log(autocomplete.getPlace());
    });
}

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

<input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50">
```

From the console in my browser I can see that the getPlace.geometry.location.lat is empty. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getPlace.geometry.location.lat` is a function, you need to call it to get its value (`getPlace.geometry.location.lat()`).

`getPlace.geometry.location.toUrlValue(6)` will give you the comma separated coordinates.

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    console.log("lat=" + autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location.lat());
    console.log(autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location.toUrlValue(6));
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50">
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to call a separate Google API to get Place Details. The documentation is present at [this official link](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#fields).

The request URL is the following.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4&fields=geometry,name,rating,formatted_phone_number&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```